# Code Error in 'Else If' statement

Tags: java

I faced an error in the below code ...

```
elseif(option.equals("S")||option.equals("s"))  // Error Expected Symbol ;
{
   ScientificCalculator sc=new ScientificCalculator();
   sc.Calc();
}
```

If I put semicolon after elseif thn it not execute else if statement what i do

Comment: You are missing a space `else if`

Comment: elseif should be else if

Comment: `If I put semicolon after elseif thn it not execute else if statement what i do` Yes, this is how it works!

Comment: People sure come to SO without investigating the problem first rather quickly.

Comment: Hey please, did anyone read the question? the elseif seems to be a typo, the question was of different nature...

Comment: This problem may be a symptom of a deeper problem - assuming Java is just like some other language that does have `elseif` as a keyword.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan or just a typo. Judging from the question, the OP would report the syntax error, if he really had an issue with that. (not that the quality of the question itself is any better than the elseif case...)

Answer (score 4):

You need to put space between elseif and for string comparison you can use equalsIgnoreCase for ignore case

```
   else if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) 
   {
        ScientificCalculator sc=new ScientificCalculator();
        sc.Calc();
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't know `elseif`, you need `else if`.

Your code can also be shortened to:

```
else if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try else if and also instead of writing or(||) try to use equalsIgnorecase method of string class. so rewrite your code as below.I am not saying you are writing wrong code by using or but using equalsIgnorecase will prevent extra check and it will also improve code readeability

```
else if(option.equalsIgnoreCase("S")) 
{
   ScientificCalculator sc=new ScientificCalculator();
   sc.Calc();
}
```

Comment: Thanku.....actually I m new in programming field so little knowing abouts all the methods and statements

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a space between your two keywords `else` and `if`.

```
else if(option.equals("S")||option.equals("s")) { /// rest to follow
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `else if`, not `elseif`.

```
else if(option.equals("S")||option.equals("s"))  
{
   ScientificCalculator sc=new ScientificCalculator();
   sc.Calc();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java uses `else if`.

elseif is wrong syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> If I put semicolon after elseif thn it not execute else if statement what i do

Yes, this is the expected behaviour! And a **common mistake** to never forget once having had to debug one.

```
if(someCondition); //BAD BAD BAD 
          //an empty code block is run when someCondition is true -- not very useful
{...instructions...} //these are run regardless of someCondition
```

Also, these are common mistakes:

```
for(int i=0;i<1000;i++); //BAD BAD BAD!
{ ... instructions ... } //this is only run once, regardless of i. 
          //Actually i is out of context here, so compiler will point it out...



int i=0;
while(i<1000); //BAD BAD BAD!
{...instructions...} //never run, as the while loop (thanks jlordo) runs infinitely
          //i is valid, and has the value of 1 - so compiler will be quiet...
```

Comment: `//run only once` is wrong. It will **never** run, because `while(i<1000); ` is an infinite loop.

Comment: @jlordo true! Or even better: while(true); :)

Answer (score 0):

there is no such Thing as:

```
if {} elseif{}
```

there exists:

```
if
{}
else 
{
if //Independent if
 {}
}
```

while Java let you write this as:

```
if{}
else if{}
```